# users in openLDAP Groups on Windows Server not gaining access to share

Tags: windows, samba, openldap

I have openldap and samba PDC setup. My windows server is a member of the samba Domain. I have a group created with users. I can see the group on the windows 2008 server, however when I add this group to a share on the windows server and I grant this group read/write access, my users in the group are unable to gain access to the share. When however; I directly add a user to the group (also coming from LDAP) it works.

How can I make windows see or allow users in my openLDAP group to gain access to the share?

One additional thing to clarify few things here. On my SambaPDC I have a group named "Domain Users" which is of the type Well-Known Entity" This group has users who are supposed to be windows administrators on any machine they login to. Since it is a well-known entity in Windows 'world' it is merged with the local Administrators' group on any computer the user login to. This is to make everyone know users in LDAP in groups works fine but the reason why this other group which is a domain level group doesn't allow/permit users to shares which the group have access to is a mystery to me. Any help is appreciated.